# Is it the efficeint program to rotate array in left direction?

Tags: c, arrays, rotation

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main()
{
    int i,j,l,m,n;
    j=0;
    printf("\nenter 5 element single dimension array\n");
    printf("enter shift rate\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    /* Here we take input from user that by what times user wants to rotate the array in left. */

    int arr[5],arrb[n];
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }

    /* Here we have taken another array. */

    for(i=0;i<=4;i++){
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        arrb[j]=arr[i];
        j++;
        // These loop will shift array element to left by position which's entered by user.
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<=3;i++){
        arr[i]=arr[i+n];
    }
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++){
        if(n==1 && i==4)
            break;
        if(n==2 && i==3)
            break;
        if(n==3 && i==2)
            break;
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
    }

    //To combine these two arrays. Make it look like  single array instead of two
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d",arrb[i]);
    }
    // Final sorted array will get printed here
}
```

Comment: Can you insert your comments as comments in the code? Your text in between the code is not good if we want to copy/paste the code. Also comments like `Here i have addded standered library.` are not necessary, we can see the includes.

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < n; i++) { arrb[j] = arr[i]; j++; }` no need for two variables, you can simply `arrb[i] = arr[i];`, however, if `n` is greater than 5, you access  `arr` out of its bounds -> undefined behaviour!

Comment: Would this not be a better fit for [codereview.se]?

Comment: Could you please show me an Input and a desired Output?  If the array contains 1,2,3,4,5 and the user says 3, do you need to rotate that array to look like this: 3,4,5,1,2 ?

Comment: the posted code prompts the user to enter a 5 element array, but fails to actually enter that array at that time, but rather prompts the user for the amount the array is to be shifted.  Then, later, inputs the 5 element array values.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it the efficeint program to rotate array in left direction?

Actually, very complicated, and some problems contained:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    arrb[j] = arr[i];
    j++;
}
```

Why not simply:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
     arrb[i] = arr[i];
}
```

There is no need for a second variable. Still, if `n` is greater than five, you get into trouble, as you will access `arr` out of its bounts (undefined behaviour!). At least, you should check the user input!

```
for(i = 0; i <=3 ; i++)
{
    arr[i] = arr[i + n];
}
```

Same problem: last accessible index is 4 (four), so n must not exceed 1, or you again access the array out of bounds...

Those many 'if's within the printing loop for the first array *cannot* be efficient...

You can have it much, much simpler:

```
int arr[5], arrb[5];
//               ^

for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    arrb[i] = arr[(i + n) % 5];
```

This does not cover *negative* values of n, though.

```
    arrb[i] = arr[(((i + n) % 5) + 5) % 5];
```

would be safe even for negative values... All you need now for the output is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    printf("%d ", arrb[i]);
```

There would be one last point uncovered, though: if user enters for `n` a value greater than `INT_MAX - 4`, you get a signed integer overflow, which again is undefined behaviour!

We can again cover this by changing the index formula:

```
arrb[i] = arr[(5 + i + (n % 5)) % 5];
```

`n % 5` is invariant, so we can move it out of the loop:

```
n %= 5;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    arrb[i] = arr[(5 + i + n) % 5];
```

Finally, if we make `n` positive already outside, we can spare the addition in the for loop.

```
n = ((n % 5) + 5) % 5;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    arrb[i] = arr[(i + n) % 5]; // my original formula again...
```

Last step is especially worth considering for very long running loops.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this (you should check that 0 <= n <= 5, too):

```
int b[5];
int k = 0;
for(i=0; i<5; i++){

    if (i < 5 - n)
        b[i] = arr[i+n];
    else
    {
        b[i] = arr[k];
        k++;
    }
}
```

Array b is used to save the rotated matrix.